# Flask User Login - check if user exists

Tags: python, mysql, flask, authentication

I've implemented a login for my flask application, it works when I log users in with the correct credentials, however when I attempt to login with a user that does not exist, I'm hit with this error message:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

How can I fix this to ensure that there is a check in place that will return a message, rather then an error ?[image: Traceback]

```
# user login
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # Get Fields Username & Password
    # Client Side Login & Validation handled by wtforms in register class
        username = request.form['username']
        usr_entered = request.form['password']
        #usr_entered = {k: (v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in usr_entered()}


        cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True,buffered=True)
# Need to check if the username exists in the db first
# Get User By Username
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =%s", [username])
        if cursor is not None:
        # Get Stored Hased and Salted password - Need to change fetch one to only return the one username
            data =cursor.fetchone()
            password = data['password']
# Compare Password with hashed password- Bcrypt
            if bcrypt.checkpw(usr_entered.encode('utf-8'),password.encode('utf-8')):
        #if (usr_entered==password):
                app.logger.info('Password Matched')
                session['logged_in'] = True 
                session['username'] = username

                flash('You are now logged in','success')
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            # Close Connection
                cursor.close()
            else:
                error = 'Invlaid Username or Password'
                return render_template('login.html',error=error)

    else: 
       error = 'Username not found'
       return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: Can you post more info from traceback? at least traceback tells an error line. FYI: this is your error source - `x = None; print(x['key'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The problem is that you are trying to get 'password' even if the username is not found in the database. In other words, if the username is not found, you will get an empty cursor object.
You can change your code to:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        usr_entered = request.form['password']
    cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =%s", [username])
    if cursor is not None:
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        try:
            password = data['password']
        except Exception:
            error = 'Invalid Username or Password'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)

        if bcrypt.checkpw(usr_entered.encode('utf-8'), password.encode('utf-8')):
            app.logger.info('Password Matched')
            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['username'] = username

            flash('You are now logged in', 'success')
            cursor.close()
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        

        else:
            error = 'Invalid Username or Password'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    else:
        error = 'Invalid Username or Password'
        return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    return render_template('login.html')
```

This is one way to solve your problem. You could to it with with if sentences. I also moved `cursor.close()` before `return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))`. In your version the `cursor.close()` would be unreachable.

## Additional info

Another security measure is to never inform the person what part of  username/password they got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error log, it looks like the cursor doesn't return `None` if it can't find a user. Use the debugging feature of Flask to tell what the value of data is when a user wasn't found, then update your if statement to have the correct value. If you wanted to be lazy you could just type `if data['password']` though.

Comment: I'm not to sure how to debug, i've used app.debug=True, however I cannot see what the cursor value is when incorrect.

Comment: you can add `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` and press `n` for next line to debug on console.